# In RDBMS, how to ensure that an attribute renders certain other attributes same for all records having that attribute

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, rdbms

Table :

```
SOFTWARE
----------------
PNAME (VARCHAR), 
TITLE (VARCHAR), 
DEVIN (VARCHAR), 
SCOST (NUMBER),
DCOST (NUMBER), 
SOLD (NUMBER)
```

How do I ensure that whenever I insert values into the table, the `TITLE`, `COSTS` and `SOLD` columns have same values whenever used as a set? i.e, whenever column `TITLE` has a value `x`, columns `SCOST`, `DCOST` and `SOLD` have same values `a , b` and `c` for all records where `TITLE` is `x`, `PNAME` and/or `DEVIN` may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [APC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44043468/1509264) suggested, normalise your tables. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE software_titles (
  title VARCHAR2(200)
        CONSTRAINT software_titles__title__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  scost NUMBER,
  dcost NUMBER,
  sold  NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE software_development (
  title VARCHAR2(200)
        CONSTRAINT software_dev__title__nn NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT software_dev__title__fk REFERENCES software_titles ( title ),
  pname VARCHAR2(200),
  devin VARCHAR2(200)
);

CREATE VIEW software IS
  SELECT t.*,
         d.pname,
         d.devin
  FROM   software_titles t
         INNER JOIN
         software_development d
         ON ( t.title = d.title );
```

Comment: This gave me the general idea, but the view was just not getting created for some reason, however when I changed it to `CREATE VIEW SOFTWARE AS SELECT T.*, D.PNAME, D.DEVIN FROM SOFTWARE_TITLES T, SOFTWARE_DEVELOPMENT D WHERE T.TITLE = D.TITLE ;` it worked, so thank you!

Comment: @user8029928 I'd mistakenly left off the join condition - its there now and should work.

Answer (score 0):

> "In RDBMS, how to ensure that an attribute renders certain other attributes same for all records having that attribute"

By normalizing your data structure. You need a separate table for `TITLE`, `SCOST`, `DCOST` and `SOLD`. Primary key probably `TITLE`.

Your existing table has a foreign key referencing this new table.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to avoid this approach as I'm supposed to stick with the schema of the given table. Could there be a workaround?